# get Attribute default store view label list

Tags: attributes

I'm looking for a function that get all labels of a specific attribute. However the label that I get is the admin view. I would like to show the default store view instead.

Here is my current wrong code :

```
 $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', '81');
 foreach ( $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true) as $option){
    /*some stuff here*/
 }
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: how are you running this script? getAllOptions() will return the values based on the current scope (in your case looks like default/admin).

Comment: It's in a custom page in my design template directory. I don't know why it is set to default/admin though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all options with value using below code:

```
 $config    = Mage::getModel('eav/config');
    $attribute = $config->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'brand');// change 'brand' with your attribute code.    
    $values    = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(); // first method to get attribute option values
```

Second Method:

```
$options = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection');
$values  = $options->setAttributeFilter($attribute->getId())->setStoreFilter($storeId)->toOptionArray();
```

Now to get all labels you can use below code:

```
foreach($values as $option)
    {
        if(!empty($option['label'])){
         $_labels[] = $option['label'];
        }
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_labels);
```

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: perfect the first method works for me ! Thank you so much for your help everyone !

Answer (score 5):

you can use below code.

```
  <?php
  $productAttribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($attr);
  $_label = $productAttribute->getStoreLabel(Mage::app()->getStore()->getName());
  echo $_label;
  ?>
```

The above code will give the attribute label as per store wise.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but like I said I would like to get all the labels of a specific attribute.

Answer (score 1):

this will help you

```
// Here you can have whole model of perticular attribute.
$productAttribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($attrCode);

// Now you can get it by store or can get all.
$_label = $productAttribute->getStoreLabel(Mage::app()->getStore()->getName());
echo $_label;
```

Answer (score 0):

Optimized Code:

PASS THE ATTRIBUTE ID AND OPTIONID TO THE below query - this will easily get the admin label of the corresponding attribute.

```
$attributeid = ''; // here pass the attributeid
$optionId = ''; //here pass the optionid


$query = "SELECT IF(tsv.value_id > 0, tsv.value, tdv.value) AS value FROM eav_attribute_option AS main_table
        INNER JOIN eav_attribute_option_value AS tdv ON tdv.option_id = main_table.option_id
        LEFT JOIN eav_attribute_option_value AS tsv ON tsv.option_id = main_table.option_id 
        AND tsv.store_id = 0 WHERE (attribute_id = {$attributeid}) AND (tdv.store_id = 0) and (tsv.option_id = {$optionId})";
```